# Erro ao compilar Caffe/Pycaffe

Tags: python, cmake

Estou tentando compilar Caffe em um Ubuntu 14.04, mas continuo recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python-py35
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.5m
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so] Error 1
```

Alguém tem uma ideia do que seria isso?

Answer (score 1):

Sim - você não isntalou os pacotes com os headers dessas bibliotecas no sistema, para pode compilar alguma coisa com elas.

Sempre que você for compilar um pacote - e as vezes um comando "pip install" em Python puro vai compilar, você precisa ter no sistema todas as bibliotecas necessárias.

Não existe uma regra exata de quais pacotes você precisa a priori, e os nomes podem mudar de uma distribuição Linux para outra. No Ubuntu e Debian, esses são os pacotes terminados com "-dev", (E em Redhat/fedora, "-devel").

No eu caso, deve ser suficiente digitar `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` no prompt e em seguida o mesmo para o pacote `libboost-all-dev`. Eu não estou no Ubuntu aqui - entaão não sei o nome do pacote apra libbosst Python que você precisa - para isso use o comando `apt-cache search boost|grep python` - e veja no que aparece listado o que estiver mais próximo de `libboost-python3-dev` -com esse nome, repita o comando `sudo apt-get install <nome>` .

COm esses pacotes no sistema, tente a compilação novamente.